# Creating UI without XML in android

Tags: android, xml

I am new to android programming,and I want to create UI in android without using xml files. I am having following UI with xml can I create the same UI programatically, is there any other way of doing it? some references will be very helpful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:tag="images"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="163dp"
            android:layout_height="86dp"
            app:srcCompat="logo1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="logo2" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:tag="info1"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="some text"
            android:textSize="10pt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/multilineText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="additonal Text"
            android:textSize="10pt"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="additional info 1"
            android:textSize="10pt"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enterText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:text="@string/prompt"
            android:textSize="10pt"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="password"
            android:hint="hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.10"
            android:background="@color/darkBlue"
            android:text="Verify" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:text="retry" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.58">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/expand_text_view"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                expandableTextView:animDuration="500"
                expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/expandable_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#0d0d0d"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="16dp" />
            </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
        </ScrollView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="@color/grey" />


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:expandableTextView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/expand_text_view2"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                expandableTextView:animDuration="500"
                expandableTextView:maxCollapsedLines="1">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/expandable_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#0d0d0d"
                    android:textSize="16dp" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@id/expand_collapse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:padding="16dp" />
            </com.ms.square.android.expandabletextview.ExpandableTextView>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to change UI element's attributes like button color, textsize at the runtime

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create UI run time without xml using java code.

Please add a Linear/Relative layout in xml file and then add views you want to require in it.

Here is the very simple example to create UI programmatically.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-user-interface-programmatically-in-android-application/

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of the screen there are two tabs: Design and Text 
Click on the Design tab and you can modify it from there without touching the xml.
See the attached image.
[image]